# bing maps will not display on index.cshtml?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, bing-maps

I am trying to add Bing maps to my ASP.NET Core MVC website using the standard documentation examples provided by Microsoft on their website

I have included the API key and found out that the map does load in a standard HTML document, but does not load on my index.cshtml view. I have tried various solutions such as including `onload="GetMap()"` in the body tag, but nothing has worked so far.

```
<div class="col-md-5">
    <h2>test</h2>
    <div id="myMap" style="position:relative;width:600px;height:600px; background-color: red;"></div>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap&key=[My API KEY]' async defer></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function GetMap() {
            var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap');
            //Add your post map load code here.
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

There are no error messages, only a blank page

Comment: In your sample code the Bing maps library is loaded through http - can you try change it to https? (possible your website is on https as well)

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much!

Comment: J S.. if you want to create it as the answer I will mark it.

Comment: Great, just did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bing Maps javascript in sample code is loaded via http - if the hosting website is instead on https, then the request will be blocked due to mixed content. Updating Bing Maps' src to https as well fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
        var map;
    function GetMap() {
         map = new 
          Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {});
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Answers should explain the solution rather than being a blob of unexplained code.